# ActiveCell recognition below 2nd row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a following code; splitting `ActiveCell` by"," and splitting the next column and looping it as a different rows. It works when `ActiveCell` is the first row but when it comes to the second row or below, it deletes next rows.

I am using windows 10 and office 365 version of excel

```
row_num = ActiveCell.Row
col_num = ActiveCell.Column

arr = Split(ActiveCell.Value, ",")
arr1 = Split(Cells(row_num, col_num + 1).Value, ",")

For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
Rows(row_num + UBound(arr)).Insert
Rows(row_num).Copy
Rows(row_num + i).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)

Cells(row_num + i, col_num).Value = arr(i)
Cells(row_num + i, col_num + 1).Value = arr1(i)

Next i
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
row_num = ActiveCell.row
col_num = ActiveCell.Column

arr = Split(ActiveCell.Value, ",")
arr1 = Split(Cells(row_num, col_num + 1).Value, ",")

On Error Resume Next
For i = 0 To UBound(arr)

Rows(row_num + i + 1).Insert
Cells(row_num + i + 1, col_num).Value = arr(i)
Cells(row_num + i + 1, col_num + 1).Value = arr1(i)

Next i
On Error Goto 0
```

Comment: I think you are getting error because both of the columns don't make equal length array. So add a Line `On Error Resume Next`. As I have added in the Answer

Comment: I would not use`On Error Resume Next` and especially without throwing in an `On Error Goto 0`.  That's right up there with `Option Explicit` in terms of importance.  A much safer way to ignore the error is `If i <= UBound(arr1) Then Cells(row_num + i + 1, col_num + 1).Value = arr1(i)`.  Be aware that both methods suppress the error message without correcting the error so every comma delimited value in `ActiveCell` will be written to the sheet but that is not necessarily true for `ActiveCell.Offset(0,1)`

Comment: @ProfoundlyOblivious .. I know that, Added the `On Error Goto 0`, besides when dealing with arrays & Collections, I usually make use of On Error Resume Next, it's simple and do the Job. Also, I think it worked for the OP :)

Comment: @mikku ... and should know that.  After all, my comment was for the OP's benefit and I did not write anything that you have not read or said yourself a hundred times or more.

Comment: Yes, I appreciate that @ProfoundlyOblivious .. That's why I added the Line in the Answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You have not shared any sample data or explained what your program is supposed to do; so, presently, I cannot tell if your algorithm is all manner of wrong or if it does what you want and the only problem is the data loss.  What is clear, is that your program will behave differently depending on the location and contents of the `ActiveCell` and cell adjacent to the right.

Your data loss comes from pasting rows over existing data.  It looks like you swapped indexers because you paste rows at `ActiveCell + i` but you insert rows at `ActiveCell + UBound(arry1)`.  They should probably both be `i`.  Or more accurately, `i + 1`.  You need the `+ 1` because your `For` loop starts at `0`

Basically, your first iteration copies `Rows(1)` and pastes `Rows(1)` into `Rows(1)` and then you start overwriting data until the end of the loop.

It is not clear if you expect the program to read subsequent lines of data or if you need to work with different numbers of commas in `ActiveCell` and the cell immediately adjacent to the right.  A difference of one comma will either cause `arry2` to trigger an invalid range error or it will have elements that were not written to the sheet.

Try using F8 if you are not certain what the result will be.  It steps line by line through your code.  Be sure to have the locals and the immediate window up as well. This way you can test and evaluate different segments while the program is paused and you can see what's happening.

My interpretation of this problem is like the answer above because it inserts new rows to prevent data loss; but unlike the answer above, this also loops between the `ActiveCell` and the last row in the `CurrentRegion` to parse the data, it does not use Copy or Paste because it is superfluous, and each array is evaluated to ensure every element is written to the sheet without generating an invalid range error in the array.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ProfoundlyOblivious()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim largest_ubound As Long
    Dim first_row_num As Long
    Dim last_row_num As Long
    Dim current_row_num As Long
    Dim col_num As Long
    Dim arr() As String
    Dim arr1() As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    first_row_num = ActiveCell.Row
    col_num = ActiveCell.Column

    With ActiveCell.CurrentRegion
        last_row_num = .Row + .Rows.Count - 1
    End With

    For current_row_num = last_row_num To first_row_num Step -1

        arr = Split(Cells(current_row_num, col_num).Value, ",")
        arr1 = Split(Cells(current_row_num, col_num + 1).Value, ",")
        largest_ubound = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(UBound(arr), UBound(arr1))

            For i = largest_ubound To 0 Step -1

                Rows(current_row_num + 1).Insert
                If i <= UBound(arr) Then Cells(current_row_num + 1, col_num).Value = arr(i)
                If i <= UBound(arr1) Then Cells(current_row_num + 1, col_num + 1).Value = arr1(i)

            Next i

    Next current_row_num

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I down Voted your answer because It will be better if you can explain step by Step with points. It seems like you are confirming half of the stuff from OP in your answer, which can be done using Comments section just below the Question.

Comment: @Mikku Valid point.  Even though I identified the problem and solution in the second paragraph, walk through the error from the first to the nth output, find two more potential errors (one of which manifested itself in your answer), and offer some tips for self help.... even though I did all of that, your point remains valid.  The question has been answered so I doubt the OP will come back and provide details - I guess I'll just have to cough up some code that solves the problems I mentioned.

Comment: @ProfoundlyOblivious - or you can just delete this answer :)

Comment: Haha ... Cool :)